# Harmonic MODIS trend in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: modis, google-earth-engine

I would like to plot in a histogram the difference between the real SAVI values and the harmonic trend.

I use this code and I cannot make it.

```js
// Load a collection of Landsat TOA reflectance images.
var landsatCollection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD13Q1');

// Set the region of interest to a point.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Point([-121.14, 37.98]);

// The dependent variable we are modeling.
var dependent = 'NDVI';

// The number of cycles per year to model.
var harmonics = 1;

// Make a list of harmonic frequencies to model.
// These also serve as band name suffixes.
var harmonicFrequencies = ee.List.sequence(1, harmonics);

// Function to get a sequence of band names for harmonic terms.
var constructBandNames = function(base, list) {
  return ee.List(list).map(function(i) {
    return ee.String(base).cat(ee.Number(i).int());
  });
};

// Construct lists of names for the harmonic terms.
var cosNames = constructBandNames('cos_', harmonicFrequencies);
var sinNames = constructBandNames('sin_', harmonicFrequencies);

// Independent variables.
var independents = ee.List(['constant', 't'])
  .cat(cosNames).cat(sinNames);


// Function to add an NDVI band, the dependent variable.
var addNDVI = function(image){
  return image
    .addBands(image.expression(
      '(1 + L) * float(nir - red)/ (nir + red + L)',
      {
        'nir': image.select('sur_refl_b02'),
        'red': image.select('sur_refl_b01'),
        'L': 0.5,
      }))
    .rename('NDVI')};



// Function to add a time band.
var addDependents = function(image) {
  // Compute time in fractional years since the epoch.
  var years = image.date().difference('2000-01-01', 'year');
  var timeRadians = ee.Image(years.multiply(2 * Math.PI)).rename('t');
  var constant = ee.Image(1);
  return image.addBands(constant).addBands(timeRadians.float());
};

// Function to compute the specified number of harmonics
// and add them as bands.  Assumes the time band is present.
var addHarmonics = function(freqs) {
  return function(image) {
    // Make an image of frequencies.
    var frequencies = ee.Image.constant(freqs);
    // This band should represent time in radians.
    var time = ee.Image(image).select('t');
    // Get the cosine terms.
    var cosines = time.multiply(frequencies).cos().rename(cosNames);
    // Get the sin terms.
    var sines = time.multiply(frequencies).sin().rename(sinNames);
    return image.addBands(cosines).addBands(sines);
  };
};

// Filter to the area of interest, mask clouds, add variables.
var harmonicLandsat = landsatCollection
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .map(addNDVI)
  .map(addDependents)
  .map(addHarmonics(harmonicFrequencies));

// The output of the regression reduction is a 4x1 array image.
var harmonicTrend = harmonicLandsat
  .select(independents.add(dependent))
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearRegression(independents.length(), 1));

// Turn the array image into a multi-band image of coefficients.
var harmonicTrendCoefficients = harmonicTrend.select('coefficients')
  .arrayProject([0])
  .arrayFlatten([independents]);

// Compute fitted values.
var fittedHarmonic = harmonicLandsat.map(function(image) {
  return image.addBands(
    image.select(independents)
      .multiply(harmonicTrendCoefficients)
      .reduce('sum')
      .rename('fitted'));
});

// Plot the fitted model and the original data at the ROI.
print(ui.Chart.image.series(fittedHarmonic.select(['fitted','NDVI']), roi, ee.Reducer.mean(), 250)
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Harmonic model: original and fitted values',
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
}));

// Pull out the three bands we're going to visualize.
var sin = harmonicTrendCoefficients.select('sin_1');
var cos = harmonicTrendCoefficients.select('cos_1');

// Do some math to turn the first-order Fourier model into
// hue, saturation, and value in the range[0,1].
var magnitude = cos.hypot(sin).multiply(5);
var phase = sin.atan2(cos).unitScale(-Math.PI, Math.PI);
var val = harmonicLandsat.select('NDVI').reduce('mean');

// Turn the HSV data into an RGB image and add it to the map.
var seasonality = ee.Image.cat(phase, magnitude, val).hsvToRgb();
Map.centerObject(roi, 11);
Map.addLayer(seasonality, {}, 'Seasonality');
Map.addLayer(roi, {}, 'ROI');
```

I get the error: **Error generating chart: ImageCollection.reduce: Error in map(ID=MOD13Q1_005_2000_02_18):
Image.rename: The number of names must match the number of bands.  Have 13, found 1.**

Comment: Quite a bit of code here. Did you try to localize the error by turning off some of the code paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the brackets of your addNDVI function

```js
// Function to add an NDVI band, the dependent variable.
var addNDVI = function(image){
  return image
    .addBands(image.expression(
      '(1 + L) * float(nir - red)/ (nir + red + L)',
      {
        'nir': image.select('sur_refl_b02'),
        'red': image.select('sur_refl_b01'),
        'L': 0.5,
      })
    .rename('NDVI'))};
```

[code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1d00dce5c2548d71c5a9335750b01bac)